# route 53 CNAME with Nginx

Tags: nginx, dns, cname, amazon-route53

I have a domain and its DNS entries are managing using AWS Route53.

I have 30 servers on a datacenter which only have private IPs, and the sites hosted on these servers are loading using a nginx proxy server which have public IP.

For this, I have created an A record (say *.abc.com A IPofproxy), then I added some redirection rules on proxy server to load the corresponding sites.

redirection rule on proxy server are as follows :

1.abc.com redirects to 1.1.1.1

2.abc.com redirects to 2.2.2.2

3.abc.com redirects to 3.3.3.3 , etc.

But now am facing an issue with the CNAMEs,

The issue is, 
I created some CNAME records like :

abc.abc.com CNAME 1.abc.com

def.abc.com CNAME 2.abc.com

fgh.abc.com CNAME 3.abc.com , etc

Then I tried to access all of the above domains (abc.abc.com , def.abc.com, etc), but all the sites are pointing to only one server which is the first one on redirection rules.

I am new to nginx, it would be great if anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your configuration correctly, the issue you're experiencing is not specifically related to either Route 53 or Nginx.

Instead, it's related to how web browsers interact with DNS entries.  You'd have this issue with any reverse proxy server.

You have to configure each CNAME entry in your proxy, individually, because the browser doesn't care about the CNAME entry -- the `Host:` header sent with each request is the hostname the browser *started with*, not the hostname the browser ended up with after any CNAMEs were traversed.

```
a.example.com  IN  A     203.0.113.1
b.example.com  IN  CNAME a.example.com.
```

A request for `b.example.com` will be routed by the proxy according to its rules for `b.example.com` and *not* by its rules for `a.example.com`, because the CNAME does not change the browser's `Host:` header, which is what the proxy is almost certainly using for its routing decision.

If you want requests for `b.example.com`, it must be configured in the proxy, and not only in the DNS.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594077/aws-route53-nginx-django-host-2-applications-with-cname