# AWS Route53 + Nginx + Django, host 2 applications with CNAME

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am trying to host 2 applications in aws EC2 instances.
I am using dockerlized nginx, django.
The 2 apps are 2 separate django containers.
I added record

```
Record A => www.main.com XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Record CNAME => www.aap2.main.com www.main.com
```

Now, how should I configure Nginx so that
if user access with URL [www.main.com](http://www.main.com), it is served with app1
and if user access with URL [www.aap2.main.com](http://www.aap2.main.com), it is served with app2?

Also can I use the SSL certificate which I got for [www.main.com](http://www.main.com)?

I tried playing around with nginx.conf file but did not have luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can proxy pass traffic.

```
server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    www.main.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://<main app container name or ip>:<main app container port>;
   }
}

server {
  listen         80;
  server_name    www.aap2.main.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://<aap2 container name or IP>:<aap2 container port>;
   }
}
```

nginx will listen to port 80 for both application and route traffic based on hostname. You can change listening port as your wish. you need to sping up container with `--name` and spin up nginx with `--link <connected container>` to work with container name inside nginx conf.

Comment: by the way, do you know we can do the same with different domain name, not subdomain like 
CNAME www.main.com -> www.other.com 
using Route53 in AWS?

Answer (score -2):

You have to use two server blocks and you have to use two different ports for two websites because you can't run two different websites on the same port. Let's assume you want to host domain-one and domain-two on the same ec2 instance server so you can use port 8000 for domain-one and use port 8001 for domain-two.

Also don't forget to point ec2 instance server ip on your domain. As u said u already did it but here I also want to explain it for others people so they can learn:

You need to point your server's IP address to yourdomain.com and www yourdomain.com. If you haven't set it up for the www version, people won't be able to find your website when they search for it using www.

go to your domain DNS settings

**config for set yourdomain.com**

choose A record then put `@` as hostname then puts the server ip in value fields

**config for set www version**

choose A record then put www as hostname then puts the server ip in value fields

Nginx configuration for hosting two sperate domains on same server:

```
server {
     listen 8000;
     listen [::]:8000;
     server_name domain-one.com www.domain-one.com;

     root /var/www/domain-one.com/html;

     index index.html index.htm;

     location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }
}


server {
     listen 8001;
     listen [::]:8001;
     server_name domain-two.com www.domain-two.com;

     root /var/www/domain-two.com/html;

     index index.html index.htm;

     location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
     }
}
```

Comment: I have A record for both with and without www for main.com. Then I added CNAME record for app2.main.com to main.com and www.app2.main.com to www.main.com.

In addition to the server blocks, I had to add this block below to make it work. Probably because the CNAME redirect to main.com already before ngix.
server {
    if ($host = www.aap2.main.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

    if ($host =  www.aap2.main.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


    server_name aap2.main.com www.aap2.main.com;

    listen 80;
    return 404;
}

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot accept this as answer since it did not work.

Comment: if the suggested solution did not work as expected, it does not necessarily mean there is an issue with the provided code or answer. The concept explained is correct, and the approach outlined should generally work. When deploying any project on a VPS server, there are various factors that can contribute to issues, such as having an incorrect version of a package, incorrect configuration of Nginx, or other misconfigurations. It's important to consider these factors and ensure all components are properly set up and configured.

Comment: Thank you for your proposed solution, If you can see the accepted answer, it is important to listen to the  same port.